# apt-cacher/approx equivalent for Centos

Tags: centos, yum, package-management

I am looking at setting up several Centos machines in my network and would like to have them update from a centralised server on the network. I am hoping to save bandwidth by not having to update each OS from the internet.

The solutions I have found require me to mirror the entire centos repository, which I find to be a terrible waste of storage considering that I would only ever be using a fraction of the packages available.

The solution I am looking for would allow all machines to point to a local yum server for packages and if the latter doesn't have the requested package, get it from the www and cache it for the next request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`http-replicator`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/http-replicator/) or [`mrepo`](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/mrepo/).